# How to make MKMapView:showAnnotations animate smoothly?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

If I add some annotations then call MKMapView:showAnnotations: then the default animation is very poor and jerky, not what I would expect (where something like MKMapView rescaleToCoordinate isn't jerky).

Is there anyway to make MKMapView:showAnnotations move and zoom the map without it looking terrible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your map transitions look jerky is because you set "animated: false"
mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: false)

change it to:
mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
and your annotations will become smooth.